# Image overhead iframe

Tags: html, image, iframe

I want to place a image over an `iframe`. To understand better, I attached the image bellow.

How can I do that?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `position: absolute;` and `z-index`

http://jsfiddle.net/t35vL/

HTML:

```
<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/"></iframe>
<img src="http://flickholdr.com/600/400/dogs">​
```

CSS:

```
iframe{
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border : 2px solid  black;
  z-index: 2;
}

img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

...that way the the image is layered **over** the iframe and will prevent clicking inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    <iframe name="inlineframe" src="sample.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" width="500" height="180" marginwidth="5" marginheight="5" ></iframe>
    <div style="position:absolute;
    left:0px; //edit as per iframe placement
    top:0px; //edit as per iframe placement
    z-index:-1;
    padding:5px;"> 
    <img src="rac_ftp.PNG" width="500" height="180" />
    </div>
```